# Why was this homebrew question held as Too Broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132858/41726) was held as Too Broad, but it just as narrow in scope as many of the other good homebrew questions are. It provided one homebrew creation and asked for an evaluation. We've left many questions just like this open:

- [Is this homebrew terran race balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127765/41726)
- [Is this homebrew whip blade balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123160/41726)
- [Is this "Master of Masks" homebrew Bard archetype balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73015/41726)
- [Is this Eldritch Crystal Familiar overpowered?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105443/41726)

What makes this question different? Is it purely the length of the homebrew. I would argue that a person making the decision not to answer a question because of the work required is fine. However, if it was closed just because it's long that doesn't seem to be the purpose of that site function. There are other users willing to put in the work.

**Did I miss a more obvious and justified close reason**? (there are no comments explaining why it was closed)

Comment: @NautArch sorry about that. I couldn't think of the right word. I meant more like incongruent with site policy (since length is not a factor in topicality). Malicious certainly has a very inaccurate meaning.

Comment: No worries - but it felt especially odd given your self-answer to this and how it was a reasonable closure reason based on that.

Answer (score 13):

### The question asks for a rebalancing not for an evaluation

The specific wording is what matters here.

> How should this homebrewed class be made into something that will not unbalance the game?

... has an infinite number of solutions. If it instead just said "what parts of this class will unbalance the game?" it would be fine.

Comment: If this is the case, I suggest we simply change the title and thesis as this is clearly what the OP requires of the experts on the site.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the asker already recognizes that the class is unbalanced - which is why they're asking how to fix it. So such a change in scope should probably be run by them first.

Comment: And how to fix things seems outside of our scope. It's an idea generation question at that point.

Comment: I’m confused about what’s going on here. @DavidCoffron, you appear to be arguing with yourself?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I realized after writing the question why people may have voted to close and figured I'd self answer and leave the question here in case someone else was wondering